# Where to find the {parent-id} of a drive item?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to [upload a file](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_put_content) into my organization's SharePoint using Microsoft Graph but I can't find `{parent-id}` for the following endpoint:

```
PUT /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

Is the `{parent-id}` supposed to be the `id` of the parent directory that file will be inserted into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. As an example, the following would upload a file named `MyFile.txt` into a folder named `MyFolder` in my account's OneDrive:

```
PUT /me/drive/root:/MyFolder/MyFile.txt:/content
```

The URI is broken down into the following components:

- Drive Path (`/me/drive/root`) - This tells Graph which `drive` you want to address. The URI `/me/drive/root` address the root of your account's OneDrive. You could also address another user's drive using `/users/{userPrincipalName}/drive/root` or a SharePoint Site's default Document Library using `/sites/{site-id}/drive/`.
- File Path (`:/MyFolder/MyFile.txt:`) - This tells Graph which file you want to address. If you want to put the file in the root of the Drive you could use `:/MyFile.txt:`. If you want to put it within a folder two levels deep you could use `:/Folder1/Folder2/MyFile.txt`.
- File Content (`/content`) - This tells Graph that you want to address a file's content (i.e. the contents of `MyFile.txt`) rather than it's meta-data (i.e. the date `MyFile.txt` was created).

Comment: What does these indicate: ' : ' ?

Comment: The `:` bookends a "path". For example, instead of the team site's `id` you can use it's from the URL `:/teams/{teamname}:`. Generally, this makes for far more readable code since almost no one knows a site bug it's GUID.

Comment: what about the file path of a folder inside a document library in SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint should work the same way. OneDrive for Business is essentially just a SharePoint document library.

Comment: I am trying to use this end point -> "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{folder_name}/{file_name}:/{content}" to upload a file to a sharepoint drive, this share point drive is on MS Teams' Files tab, I can't figure out what the folder_name should be.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, I figured it out thanks, folder_name for a Microsoft Team would be the name of the channel.